# PHP Memory Exhaustion when storing sql query in list

Tags: php, sql, memory, memory-management, out-of-memory

I want to results of a SQL query in a list but since it has many data it causes memory exhaustion.

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes)

This is how I try to do it. Is there another way without causing a memory exhaustion? Increasing memory is no option since there will occur even bigger datasets.

```
$sql = $pdoconnect->query('SELECT id FROM contacts');
$id_liste = $sql->fetchAll();
```

I already tried it with a loop instead but it was the same:

```
while($row = $statement->fetch()){
    $id_liste[] = $row['id'];  }
```

Comment: Your query has used 536 MB and exhausted the allocated memory of your process. Either you allocate more memory to your process or rethink the approach. Do you really need to load the whole list of IDs in RAM?

Comment: please tell us what will be the remaining operations when you loaded data into  $id_liste[] ?

Comment: I need to save the whole list of IDs in a list. I don't know if there is an approach without loading it in RAM

Comment: But after storing the whole list in a list (in memory) , what is the next step ? saving it somewhere ? do sorting / other operations ?

Comment: @KenLee after loading them in $id_liste I use a foreach loop to iterate through the list and use every single ID for a certain API and get an XML file which I use to insert some data into another db table

Comment: Then just do it on the level on DB, Use a looping,  retrieve the record **one by one** and use each ID to call the API and insert data into another db table. There is no need to load all the data into memory at the same time.

Comment: @KenLee What do you mean when you say on the level on DB?

Comment: the level **of** DB (sorry I typed on)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use generators. This is what they're designed for.

Rewrite your code like this:

```php
function fetchContacts()
{

   $result = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM contacts');

   while($record = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

       yield $record;

   }
}

// Then elsewhere in your code where you actually use the contacts:
foreach (fetchContacts() as $contact) {
    // All of your code here.
}
```

PHP will only use as much memory as is required for each field instead of every record.  It should work.

Also, try to use LIMITs in your SQL, because you probably don't want to process all 100,000 contacts at once, right?

Comment: The last upvote on this answer put me above 20,000 rep. Thank you so much!